# What is the equivalent of JavaScript's decodeURIcomponent in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, decode, encode

I have a string with unicode characters that I am transferring via HTTP. This string was encoded with Javascript's `encodeURIcomponent()`.  Is there an equivalent function in php to Javascript's `decodeURIComponent()`?

Answer (score 73):

```
urldecode()
```

However you do not need to use it on $_REQUEST variables, which are already decoded automatically.

Comment: i have used $_POST for fetching,but urldecode() doesnt work on unicode characters.

Comment: <?php
  function utf8_urldecode($str) {
    $str = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($str));
    return html_entity_decode($str,null,'UTF-8');;
  }
?>

Comment: @ExplosionPills was that double semicolon at the end a typo?

Comment: Side note: I am using `encodeURIComponent()` to pass data to a Laravel application and the request doesn't seem to automagically decode the value.

Comment: Be careful: `urldecode('+') === ' '` and `decodeURIComponent('+') === '+'`. Currently dont know why.

Answer (score 7):

`rawurldecode()`
which does not decode plus to space charactor