# Ignore or Remove Hash Mark/Anchor In GET Request

Tags: javascript, php, post, get

I have an application that is getting posted via HTTP GET to and occasionally my users are putting in hash marks (pound signs) and it breaks everything from that point forward in the post.  I do not mind at all  using javascript or anything else.

Basically, what I want is if the GET URL looks like this:
http://some.thing/index.php?addres=123%20main%20st%#20
I want it tojust get rid of the # but keep everything else, so it would end up like:
http://some.thing/index.php?addres=123%20main%20st%20

Thanks everyone.

Comment: How are you using the url in your code? Without seeing that there is no way to help

Comment: Normally hash values are not even sent to the server

Comment: #anything should not break your page

Comment: This shouldn't be causing any issues so you should post your code, but a quick solution would be `onclick="window.location.hash = '';"`

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a postal address, so presumably you actually *want* that number sign, since it's the number of a unit.

I'm not sure how the `%#` worked its way in there but I suspect there is some regex trickery to convert spaces into `%20` but not *other* characters that must also be escaped.

Since you're sending a GET request, look into using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before sending it:

```
encodeURIComponent("123 main st #20");
"123%20main%20st%20%2320"
```

And then [decode it in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896591/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javascripts-decodeuricomponent-in-php) with `urldecode()`.